# Render to cube map on iPhone using OpenGL ES

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone, opengl-es

I'm trying to generate dynamic cube map on the `iPhone` using this code:

```
GLuint textureCubeMap;
glGenTextures(1, &textureCubeMap);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, textureCubeMap);

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_5_6_5, 0);
}

GLuint framebuffer;
glGenFramebuffers(1, &framebuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, framebuffer);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X, textureCubeMap, 0);

GLenum framebufferStatus = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if (framebufferStatus == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED) {
    Log("Unsupported");
} else if (framebufferStatus == GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
    Log("All is OK");
}
```

When I'm running this code on `iOS` simulator, I see `All is OK` message in console.
But running on `iPhone 5` with `iOS 7` prints `Unsupported` message.  As I understand iPhone does not support rendering to cube map.  But I know this is possible because I saw the game with such effect.  So my question is:  What is the correct way to generate dynamic cube map on the `iPhone` using `OpenGL ES`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the call to the following:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X + i, 0, GL_RGB, 256, 256, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting. I had looked it up when I saw the question, and the ES 2.0 spec lists RGB565 as a color-renderable format. Based on that, it seemed like what the original poster tried **should** have worked. Do you know if this limitation only applies to cube maps, or to any RGB565 textures?